# image in Cups print sent to remote network printer rises 0.10 inch per page?

Tags: printing

If I send a print-job from Ubuntu 18.04, vi cups 2.2.7 to Sun Sparcprinter on a sparcstatopin 10 running Ghostscript, the image on each subsequent page rises 0.10 inch per sheet.

Before anyone wastes his/her time with this, it would be helpful to know if anyone has ever seen this problem before.

I've tried every thing I can think of in both the filter format on the print computer and in the ppd on the ubuntu machine.

if i write a typical file to a pdf and then print it directly with the LP routine on the Sun, it prints perfectly. prints sent from the Sun to its own printer work ok. I'm pretty sure there is something causing this problem in Cups.

FWIW, in 2015 when I first set this up, it worked fine.

If this site is not the best one for something like this, please recommend one which might be better.

Comment: 1. Please also share if you have checked that it is not that printer(hardware) specific problem.  2. There is CUPS forum on github also to be specific for CUPS problem.

Comment: I gave up using CUPS for this printer. I may be the only one in the world still using one of these printers.  I finally built a spooler on the Sun SPARCstation 10 which has a crontab entry which runs it once a minute. the spooler directory is remore mounted on each of the computers which use this printer.  I print to a file which is created in the spooler directory, the spooler checks to see if a printfile has started to show up, it checks every 10 seconds to see if the file has stopped growing then prints it.